# JUnit list of methods to be executed

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to get the number of methods to be executed by JUnit for the current test class. For example if the entire test class is run by maven I should get lets say 10, but if I want to run 3 tests of that class from IntelliJ, I would like to get that number, does anyone know how and if I can achieve this?
What I am looking for would be a JUnit "context" object that has this information prior to executing a test class.
If that is not possible I would like to know if we can register a callback method that would be called automatically by JUnit after running all the tests.

Comment: So you would like to run particular subset of your unit-test via **IntelliJ** and your project is **maven** based, right?

Comment: No, I just want when running the test to get, either at the beginning or at the end, the total number of tests that were initiated for the current test class. I need this to perform a database cleanup and I can't use AfterClass or AfterAll because these require a static method and I can't obtain the required services for clean-up from the static code.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see co-relation between database cleanup and number of tests... Could you please edit the post and give some code example or more specifics? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's important the exact use case, I only wanted to know if it was possible to get the total number of methods that JUnit has to execute for a given test class.

Comment: I have added a bit more details, hope that it helps.

Comment: You can use reflection on the class and check the `@Test` annotations. But this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe you should ask the question about the problem you have with database cleanup, services and your static code.

Comment: I already used reflection to count the number of method annotated with @Test and it works fine, but only when you run the entire class. If you run a single test the counter we have in place will only increment once and when it gets compared with the number of tests methods, the database cleanup will not start.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you're looking for (though it's tough to tell) is the [TestWatcher](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html) JUnit [@Rule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Rules). It allows you to hook in some custom logic at each point in the lifecycle of each individual test. You can use it to get information when each test starts and accumulate your own information about how many and which tests ran.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sadly using this we can't get the desired outcome, this Watcher is per test, what we would need is an Watcher per class if that exists, so that we can get information like: "When has the last test method of this class finished executing?" or "How many test methods are about to be executed in this test class?". This will help us have an internal counter which is incremented after each test and compare it with the total number of tests that have to be executed and when the last one has finished, we can trigger the database clean-up.

Comment: I know that this can be accomplished by using either AfterAll or AfterClass annotations, but these require static context and from a static context I can't get hold of the required Spring beans to perform the clean-up.

Comment: @Andrei It sounds like the actual problem you're trying to solve is this database cleanup. Spring [has a lot built in to allow for testing with databases](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testing-tx), so perhaps you want to ask a question about that and why it isn't doing what you need it to.

Comment: We are using rest assured and transactions don't get propagated over http unless using SOAP as far as I know. But we found a solution to the problem, we were trying to Autowire static field directly, but after using setter injection we could use @AfterClass without any issues. Now I am not sure what do to about this question for which I no longer need an answer :-)